# "Grabbing" only selected vertices in proportional edit mode

Tags: vertices, proportional-editing

In proportional edit mode I cannot grab onto the selected vertices of my object, only the object itself (I can still see the vertices I have selected, just can't control them specifically with the grab tool). When I deselect proportional edit, I can move the selected vertices around just fine instead of moving the whole object around.

Comment: Can you see the edit circle? If not it may be too big. While editing with it, keep scrolling your mouse wheel up until the circle becomes visible. This is the proportional edit area.

Comment: Thanks! I think for whatever reason, I have to press "G" 2 times. The first time, allows me to select the object and does not affect the vertices selected, just the whole object. 

Pressing 'G' twice allows me to select the vertice(s) and then scroll to affect the change

Comment: Nevermind, I think I just got confused with how scroll worked. Now that I properly see the edit circle, I can control the vertices proportionally:)

Comment: are you in the Select tool? try the move tool to the left.

Comment: Realize that the g+g trick does not respect proportional editing. Even when proportional editing is currently active, g+g will act as if proportional editing was off.